# Drawn line not landing up in endpoint

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am doing a construction including connecting two points by a line.
Somehow the first line from K to E is OK but the one from K to M is not.
How to solve this?
Side question: is there an easier way of dividing the angle <OBA by 4?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts,thmtools}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, shapes, arrows, calc, intersections, through, backgrounds}
\newcommand{\tikzAngleOfLine}{\tikz@AngleOfLine}
\def\tikz@AngleOfLine(#1)(#2)#3{%
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
        \pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{%
        \pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=12,cap=round,>=latex]

% draw the coordinates
\draw[thin, name path=x] (-0.2cm,0cm) -- (1.1cm,0cm);
\draw[thin, name path=y] (0cm,-0.1cm) -- (0cm,0.4cm);

\coordinate (O) at (0cm,0cm) node[below left=3pt]{$O$};
\coordinate (A) at (1cm,0cm);
\coordinate (B) at (0cm,0.25cm);

\draw[thin] (A) circle(0.1pt) node[below=3pt]{$A$} -- (B) circle(0.1pt) node[left]{$B$};
\tikzAngleOfLine(B)(O){\AngleStart};
\tikzAngleOfLine(B)(A){\AngleEnd};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\alp}{(\AngleEnd+3*\AngleStart)/4};

\draw[thin,red, name path=BE] (B) -- ++(\alp:0.3cm);
\path [name intersections={of=BE and x,by=E}];
\draw (E) circle(0.1pt) node[below left=3pt]{$E$};

\draw[thin,blue, name path=BF] (B) -- ++(\alp-45:0.3cm);
\path [name intersections={of=BF and x,by=F}];
\draw (F) circle(0.1pt) node[below left=3pt]{$F$};

\node (M) [] at ($(F)!0.5!(A)$) {};
\pgfgetlastxy{\xM}{\yM}
\draw (M) circle(0.1pt) node[below left=3pt]{$M$};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rM}{1-\xM*1pt/1cm*1/12};

\draw[thin, name path=AF] ([shift=(0:\rM)] M) arc (0:180:\rM);

\path[name intersections={of=AF and y,by=K},fill=black];
\draw (K) circle(0.1pt) node[above left=3pt]{$K$};
\draw[thin,green] (K) -- (E); % neatly landing in E
\draw[thin,green] (K) -- (M); % why not landing in M?

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Trial]

Comment: Use `\coordinate (M) at ...` instead of `\node (M) [] ..`. Nodes have size, and paths are drawn to the node border.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. interesting - but then I would need something else than at ($(F)!0.5!(A)$) as that does not work for coordinates, apparently.

Comment: Ooh  Heptadecagon construction!

Comment: One way to get a coordinate at a midpoint is `\path (A)--(F) coordinate[midway](M);`
Or you can leave it as a node, then set the node size to 0 in several ways.  The easiest is to put `\node (M) [inner sep=0pt] at ...`

Comment: Hm, that was strange. An alternative then  is to draw to `M.center` instead of `M`.

Comment: @AndrewKepert That actually didn't work either, seems `\pgfgetlastxy` gets the wrong point. But `\path (A)--(F) coordinate[midway](M); \path (M);` works, as does `\coordinate(M) at ($(F)!0.5!(A)$); \path (M);`. Appending `\path(M);` makes `\pgfgetlastxy` pick up the correct point it would seem.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That indeed works - thanks!

Comment: @AndrewKepert indeed well spotted! 17-gon construction

Comment: @Maestro13 - I'd recognise it at 100 paces.  (I have versions I've made in several languages/platforms.)  @Torbjørn - interesting.  I usually don't bother diving into the innards of TikZ, so have no idea why this would be the case.  Looking at the pgfmanual, there is some vagueness about some complicated rules that TikZ uses to determine the correct answer which is right most of the time, but can be overriden when it gets it wrong — by `(M.center)` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer here is to use `\coordinate` instead of `\node`. A `coordinate` is actually a specific type of node, but it doesn't work like a text box, it's just a point. Even an empty `\node` will have a size, and a line drawn to the node stops at the node border.

However, using `\coordinate` here seems to mess with `\pgfgetlastxy`, so a couple of alternatives are

- appending `\path (M);` after specifying the coordinate:

  ```
  \coordinate(M) at ($(F)!0.5!(A)$); \path (M);
  ```

  That way `\pgfgetlastxy` picks up the correct point (it would seem).
- drawing to the `center` anchor of `M`:

  ```
  \draw[thin,green] (K) -- (M.center);
  ```